# Blank Flutter screen while using ListView Builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to make a button that adds new widget to my screen .
I'm putting my `Builder` inside an `Expanded` widget and a `FloatingactionButton` below that called the method `_addCardWidget()`
This is my Statefull screen :

```
/* Import */

class ajouterUnDocument extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ajouterUnDocument> createState() => _ajouterUnDocumentState();
}



final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

class _ajouterUnDocumentState extends State<ajouterUnDocument> {
  List<Widget> _cardList = [(InputRefNomProduit()), (InputRefNomProduit())];

  void _addCardWidget() {
    setState(() {
      _cardList.add(InputRefNomProduit());

      _cardList.add(InputQuntitePrixProduit());
    });
  }

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF2A2D3E),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Card(
          shadowColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
          color: Color(0xFF2A2D3E),
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
          elevation: 10.0,
          child: Container(
            width: 1800,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "AJOUTER UN DOCUMENT",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Divider(
                          thickness: 3,
                        ),

                        Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),    
                                  ListView.builder(
                                      itemCount: _cardList.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        return _cardList[index];
                                      }),

                                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),

                                  
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 370.0,
                            ),
                            MaterialButton(
                              color: Colors.grey[200],
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: Text(
                                "Annuler",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 20.0,
                            ),
                            MaterialButton(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 75, 100, 211),
                              onPressed: () {
                                _addCardWidget();
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                "Ajouter une nouvelle ligne",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 20.0,
                            ),
                            
                                  );
                                }
                              },
                             
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _addCardWidget,
        tooltip: 'Add',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now , all i'm getting is a blank screen and my `Debug Console`  is showing these error :

```
`Scaffold
lib\…\Screen\ajouterunDct.dart:61
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
Assertion failed:
D:\…\rendering\box.dart:1982
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#6d64a relayoutBoundary=up8"

The relevant error-causing widget was
Card
lib\…\Screen\ajouterunDct.dart:65
═════`
Assertion failed:
D:\…\rendering\box.dart:1982
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#95d37 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT"

The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
lib\…\Screen\ajouterunDct.dart:61
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Do you want to have a horizontal list?

Comment: @salihgueler: yes

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the form with SafeArea() then it should display unter the noth of the phone.
Or wrap the Form with Expanded()

Answer (score 0):

Surround your listview.builder with expanded widget and add the flex property of the expanded widget to 1. This will solve the problem with the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it inside the Container or Sized box. Assign certain height and it should work!

Answer (score 0):

change the shrinkWrap property to true

```
shrinkWrap: true,
```